# Unable to clear multiple routes from Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**The Senario:**

I have a google map and one of its functions is to show routing information from a central point to several diffrent locations on the same map.
I know that each direction object can only show one set of routes at time so I have a function that create a render object each time it is called and places the route on the map and call it for each location.

**The code:**

the function to calculate and display the route:

```
  function calculateRoot (startLocation,wayPoints,endLocation) {
            var selectedMode = $("#travelMode").val(); 
            // create a new directions service object to handle directions requests 
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            // create a directions display to display route info on the map
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            // Stops the default googlemarkers from showing
            directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));

            // create a request object
            var request = {
                origin:startLocation,
                waypoints: wayPoints,
                destination:endLocation,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
                optimizeWaypoints:true,
                provideRouteAlternatives:true,
                transitOptions: {
                    departureTime: new Date()
                }
                };   
            directionsService.route(request, function(result,status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    return directionsDisplay;
                }

                else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                    alert ('No routing can be found for this Journey');
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    alert ('The following error occoured while attempting to obtain directions information:'+'\n'+status + '\n' + 'For:'+ ' '+ request.destination);
                    return -1;
                }
            });
        }
```

**The all locations function:**

```
      function showAllRoutes(){
            if ( ! directionsArray.length < 1) {
                // if directions are already displayed clear the route info
                clearRoots();
            } 
            $('#directions').empty();
            // craete an empty waypoint array just to pass to the function
            var wayPoints = [];
            for (var i = 0; i< markerArray.length; i++) {
                 var directions = calculateRoot(startLatLng,wayPoints,markerArray[i].position); 
                     directionsArray.push(directions);

            }
            sizeMap();
            $('#directions').show();
        }
```

**The function to clear the route(s)**

```
function clearRoutes() {
            if (directionsArray.length <1 ) {
                alert ("No directions have been set to clear");
                return;

            }
            else {
                $('#directions').hide();
                for (var i = 0;i< directionsArray.length; i ++) {
                  if (directionsArray [i] !== -1) {
                      directionsArray [i].setMap(null); 
                  }
                }
                directionsArray.clear();
                map.setZoom(5);
                return;
            }   
        }
```

**The problem:**

While generating and displaying the routes seems to work fine no matter what I do I cant clear the routes from the map unless I refresh.
Am I missing something simple or can what I need to do not be done in this way, I've been trying to get this working for more than a day now and I'm stumped.
Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have function clearRoutes() but you call clearRoots();

Comment: Sorry thats just a typo on my part its not in th actual code

Comment: Just noticed that when I call the clearRoutes function with firebug on the object in the object in the routesArray is coming up as "undefined" at  directionsArray [i].setMap(null);

Answer (score 0):

The directions service is asynchronous, calculateRoot (or calculateRoute or whatever it is really called) can't return anything, you need to push the routes into a global array in the callback function.

This is your callback function:

```
function(result,status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                return directionsDisplay;
            }
```

change it to something like:

```
function(result,status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                directionsArray.push(directionsDisplay);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks geocodezip could you elaborate with an example sorry Im kind of a noob ;-).

Comment: if you want an example, post your complete code (preferably as a live map or a jsfiddle).